# place ImageView on ImageButton

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

so i want to crate a pause button for a game and i want to use the drawable button and the pause icon but it gives me this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crazyromteam.musicworldrecreation/com.crazyromteam.musicworldrecreation.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.crazyromteam.musicworldrecreation:layout/activity_game: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

here is my xml implemetation of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GameActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_button" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button_small" />
</ImageButton>

    <com.crazyromteam.musicworldrecreation.GameSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/game_bg"/>

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing ImageView inside an ImageButton tag this is a crushing issue.

Try to change ImageButton image from java/kotlin code based on there onClick event

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of why you are receiving a `RuntimeException`, the key is here in your implementation of your `ImageButton`:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_button" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button_small" />
</ImageButton>
```

You are nesting the `ImageView` within the `ImageButton`. This is not allowed as stated in the exception:
`android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`. A `ViewGroup` is a view which other views can be nested in, so when you nest a child view inside the `ImageButton`, it becomes intepreted as a `ViewGroup`, except the `ImageButton` cannot be interpreted that way. If you remove the nested `ImageView`, you will no longer receive this exception.

Your question is unclear to me as to what you are trying to attempt, but to simply state how to put the image on the `ImageButton`, declare the drawable in `android:src`, which you are already declaring on the `ImageButton`. That is where you image should go.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button_small" />
```